# Socket TCP/IP Octave

Tags: python, sockets, octave, tcpclient

I have created a socket TCP/IP server in C:

On the client-side, I used a script Octave to implement socket TCP/IP client

Even though the script has been terminated, but the server is still open, I would like to know what is the element which can keep the connection alive?

I saw that the Octave window is still open which contains the variables also, and I think that is the reason makes the connection is still alive. But I need some explanations about this problem.

I did the same things with a client in Python but the server is closed even I did not close the socket.

Comment: Please read the descriptions of both [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave]. They are **not** the same, thus please mention which of the two you're actually using (I suspect Octave) and remove the other one.

Comment: please provide some code of what you did in octave.